# Storyboarding for beginners

Tags: video

I wanna get more professional with videography and I'm looking for a structured way to make a concept before I start shooting. I'd like to be able to split a clip into scenes and determine how to film it with the equipment I have, e.g. how many cameras, what angles etc.

I read an article about storyboarding software/apps for beginners a couple days ago, but I can't find it anymore. Do you have any recommendations on how to start with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I've always just envisioned the film in my mind and sketched out (on actual paper) the shot angles.

Another option is to get miniatures of your locations, props and performers (dolls, action figures, etc.), position them as they'll be in the scene, and take photos of each of the angles you want in your storyboard. Then you have actual photos of the angles you want.

A third option is similar to the second:  Use miniatures, and then use a video camera to do the actual movements you want.  Someone could be reading lines of dialog aloud while you are shooting.  I saw a documentary showing that this was done during preproduction of *Return of the Jedi* for the speeder bike sequence on the forest moon of Endor.

With the first two options, I would have the storyboard on set with me, and put a mark next to each shot I'd gotten. That way I knew what I had left to shoot.

Answer (score 1):

DAZ3D is a great program for very quickly creating storyboards. It has a relatively short learning curve compared to other 3D applications. And it's FREE.

It comes with basic models to start. If you need specific models you can buy them (they are relatively cheap), or use simple geometry objects as place holders which you can generate in the program at no cost.

The nice thing about the program is it renders very fast in Texture mode, and you can set up cameras with actual focal lengths, so your storyboards can be built based on the lens lengths you will be using.